# App Audio Not Playing

Tags: ios, objective-c, audio, avaudioplayer

So in my file I have the following code with the intention that a music file plays in the background :

```
-(void) BackGroundMusic {
   NSString *soundPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:@"LostInTheSea" ofType:@"mp3"];
   SystemSoundID soundID;
   AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID((__bridge CFURLRef)[NSURL fileURLWithPath: soundPath], &soundID);
   AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(soundID);
}
```

And then in the view did load section I have :

```
[self BackGroundMusic];
```

I have all the toolboxes added such as AVFoundation and AudioToolbox but i can not hear any audio playing . Please help !

Comment: Have a look a this! Seems a similar issue.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8753625/sound-not-playing-xcode

Comment: Xcode is a fance editor, it is the app that is not playing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not be using system sound to play mp3 files as user523234 explains.
Use AVAudioPlayer instead. Here's an example that will loop infinitely:

```
#import "AVFoundation/AVAudioPlayer.h"
#import "AVFoundation/AVAudioSession.h"

-(void)playbgMusic {
    AVAudioPlayer *soundbgMusic;
    NSString *soundPath;
    soundPath= [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"bgMusic" ofType:@"mp3"];
    soundbgMusic = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:soundPath] error:NULL];
    soundbgMusic.volume = 1.0;
    soundbgMusic.numberOfLoops = -1;
    [soundbgMusic prepareToPlay];
    soundbgMusic.currentTime = 0.0;
    [soundbgMusic play];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the [document](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/AudioToolbox/Reference/SystemSoundServicesReference/index.html#//apple_ref/c/func/AudioServicesPlaySystemSound) for `AudioServicesPlaySystemSound`:

Sound files that you play using this function must be:

```
No longer than 30 seconds in duration

In linear PCM or IMA4 (IMA/ADPCM) format

Packaged in a .caf, .aif, or .wav file
```